# Apps Script Drive App Service - Create a file of Google Type - Mime Type

Tags: google-apps-script, mime-types

I'm using the `.createFile` method of the `DriveApp` `Folder` class.  This is the syntax:

```
createFile(name, content, mimeType)
```

The documentation is here:  [createFile Google DriveApp Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile%28String,String,String%29)

The example shows a `mimeType` setting of MimeType.HTML.

```
// Create an HTML file with the content "Hello, world!"
 DriveApp.createFile('New HTML File', '<b>Hello, world!</b>', MimeType.HTML);
```

I can type in `MimeType.` and get a list of MimeTypes, one of them being `GOOGLE_DOCS`. So I entered `MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS`. But I'm getting an execution error stating that one of the arguments is invalid.  If I type in a Mime Type of 'text/plain', I get no error.

How do I create a file with the document type of a Google Type?

If I enter a Mime Type of 'GOOGLE_DOCS' as text, it creates a file, but it creates a file with a file type of `application/octet-stream`.

If I use a MimeType of `MimeType.HTML`, I don't get an error, and the file is viewable from my Google Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DocumentApp.create('File_Name')` to create a fileType of `GOOGLE_DOCS`. DocumentApp service allows to create and manipulate Google Documents. For more details, you may check the reference.

References:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app

In order to place the recently create Document in a Folder, you may use `DriveApp`. Here is a sample code.

```
function createandPlaceInFolder(){
  //Create the document
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('My new file');
  //get it as a drive file
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  //get the target folder
  var targetFolder  = DriveApp.getFolderById('MY_FOLDER_ID');//Change it to the folder_Id
  //place the file in target folder
  targetFolder.addFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Where does it put the new file?  In the root of Drive?

Comment: Okay, I just created a file and it put it in the root.  I wonder if there is a way to use DriveApp and DocumentApp together to write directly to a folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this modified script for making sheet backups.Maybe it can be useful, it has fixed this same issue for me. It needs to enable Drive API before using it.

```
function makeCopy(fileSheetId, dstFolderId) {
  var fileSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(fileSheetId);
  var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId);
  var f = fileSheet.makeCopy(dstFolder);
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": dstFolderId}]}, f.getId());
    }
}

function run() {
  var fileSheetId = "<Sheet ID>";
  var dstFolderId = "<Destination folder ID>";
  makeCopy(fileSheetId, dstFolderId);
}
```