# Creating a Google Sheet in a specific folder with DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a Google Sheet in a specific folder on Google Drive using Google Apps Script. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob) of the `File` class:

> createFile(name, content, mimeType)
>
> Creates a file in the current folder with the given name, contents, and MIME type. Throws an exception if content is larger than 10MB.
>
> ```
> // Create an HTML file with the content "Hello, world!"
> DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile('New HTML File', '<b>Hello, world!</b>', MimeType.HTML);
> ```

And according to the `MimeType` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type):

> Enum MimeType
>
> An enumeration that provides access to MIME-type declarations without typing the strings explicitly. Methods that expect a MIME type rendered as a string (for example, 'image/png') also accept any of the values below, so long as the method supports the underlying MIME type.

There is no mention of `createFile` supporting only a subset of available MIME types. The page includes a table, which includes this MIME type:

> `GOOGLE_SHEETS    Enum    Representation of MIME type for a Google Sheets file.`

My issue lies in implementing this method of creating a file as described in the `File` documentation.

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('new folder');
var ss = folder.createFile('new sheet', '', MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
```

This will throw an error, stating

> Invalid argument: file.contentType (line 2, file "Code")

Replacing `MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS` with the string `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` obviously did not help. I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992358/how-to-fix-error-invalid-argument-file-contenttype-when-creating-new-google), but the accepted answer simply admits defeat and uses a common messy workaround by creating the file in `SpreadsheetApp`, copying it, and deleting the original. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419586/apps-script-drive-app-service-create-a-file-of-google-type-mime-type?rq=1) has a similarly disappointing accepted answer to the same problem, except for Google Docs. The `SpreadsheetApp` workaround is fine, but I'm hoping 3 years on that someone holds the answer as to how to use `createFile` properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a Spreadsheet in a particular folder via App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script)

Comment: @Kos Thanks for the link, but unfortunately not, it's still a sloppy workaround without explaining why the official method in Google's documentation doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The Google issue tracker has a long, long history of this question being asked. Way back in 2014, a Google staff member [declared](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761441#comment22) that it was a resolved issue, and they had decided that `MimeType.GOOGLE_`-type files could not be created by the `createFile` method.

> Marked as fixed.
>
> After extensive consideration, we have determined that DriveApp.createFile() should not be used to create MimeType.GOOGLE_* files.
>
> Shortly, attempting to do so will fail and result in a more descriptive error message.

Unfortunately, despite promising otherwise, the error message was never changed and the documentation was never updated to reflect this "extensive consideration".

The correct solution to add a `MimeType.GOOGLE_`-type file to a specific folder with 1 server call (no copying, removing, or updating) is

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('folder');
var file = {
    title: 'New Sheet',
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id: folder.getId()}]
}
ssId = Drive.Files.insert(file).id;
```

[`Drive.Files.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) does require the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), which you can enable on your script with [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) guide.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function createFolderAndFile() {
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('RootSub');
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.create('RootSubSheet');
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());
}
```

Comment: This is better than the copy and remove solutions, but still doesn't answer why the `MimeType` method endorsed by Google doesn't work. I'll accept it if no one else answers, because it is a good solution. Thanks

Comment: You might be able to find the answer on issue tracker the link is in the support page.